# Exception caught: org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins, gitlab

I am trying to build a docker image with Gitlab-CI using the docker-maven-plugin (provided by spotify: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin).

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <imageName>MY_REGISTRY/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
        <imageTags>
            <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
        </imageTags>
        <dockerDirectory>docker</dockerDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <serverId>my-registry</serverId>
        <registryUrl>https://MY_REGISTRY/v2/</registryUrl>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>docker-build</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>docker-push</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>push</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here is the full excepton with maven debug:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (docker-build) on project marktbeobachtung: Exception caught: org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair -> [Help 1]  

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (docker-build) on project marktbeobachtung: Exception caught
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exception caught
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:141)
    at com.spotify.docker.BuildMojo.execute(BuildMojo.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DockerCertificates.<init>(DockerCertificates.java:91)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DockerCertificates.<init>(DockerCertificates.java:57)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DockerCertificates$Builder.build(DockerCertificates.java:170)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv(DefaultDockerClient.java:1691)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.getBuilder(AbstractDockerMojo.java:146)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.buildDockerClient(AbstractDockerMojo.java:153)
    at com.spotify.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:138)
    ... 22 more
```

I get no error when I use my Jenkins.

```
mvn clean javadoc:javadoc javadoc:test-javadoc deploy -Psonar sonar:sonar
```

In Gitlab-CI I splitted maven into 4 stages:

- Build
- Test
- Code_Covergae
- Deploy

The Deploy Stage fails, I perform this command:

```
mvn deploy
```

I have no idea how I could fix this, any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/441 ?

Comment: What he meant with long format? -text is the only difference...
And the Key on Jenkins is gernerated the same way like Gitlab-runner